# How to animate an svg dashed line

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

```js
var path = document.querySelector('.path');
 var length = path.getTotalLength();
 path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
   'none';
 path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
 path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
 path.getBoundingClientRect();
 path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
   'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';
 path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
```

```html
<svg  id="test" width="800px" height="369.643px" viewBox="0 0 800 369.643" enable-background="new 0 0 800 369.643">
 <path fill="none" 
   stroke="#596E7A" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="25,25" class="path" stroke-linecap="round"
 d="M34.762,225.595c25.084,109.862,211.31,151.786,342.262,108.929 c129.701-42.448,212.358-186.755,180.357-288.095C543.096,1.19,460.075-8.983,449.372,67.834 c-15.801,113.4,167.532,164.904,318.724,34.547"/>
 </svg>

 <svg width="800px" height="369.643px" viewBox="0 0 800 369.643" enable-background="new 0 0 800 369.643">
 <path fill="none" 
   stroke="#596E7A"
 stroke-width="10"
 stroke-miterlimit="10"
 stroke-dasharray="25,25"
 stroke-linecap="round"
 d="M34.762,225.595c25.084,109.862,211.31,151.786,342.262,108.929   c129.701-42.448,212.358-186.755,180.357-288.095C543.096,1.19,460.075- 8.983,449.372,67.834
 c-15.801,113.4,167.532,164.904,318.724,34.547"/>
 </svg>
```

I get svg dashed line. I want the animation dashed line, but dashed line already change to solid. How animate down line like in top?

Answer (score 0):

The standard line drawing trick works by animating the dash offset of a dash pattern.  You can't use that same technique if the line is already dashed.

One simple way to do it would be to cover your line with another one that is the same colour as the background. Then animate that instead to reveal the dashed line underneath it.

```js
var path = document.querySelector('.path');
 var length = path.getTotalLength();
 path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
   'none';
 path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
 path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
 path.getBoundingClientRect();
 path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
   'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';
 path.style.strokeDashoffset = -length;
```

```html
<svg width="800px" height="369.643px" viewBox="0 0 800 369.643" enable-background="new 0 0 800 369.643">
 <path fill="none" 
   stroke="#596E7A"
 stroke-width="10"
 stroke-miterlimit="10"
 stroke-dasharray="25,25"
 stroke-linecap="round"
 d="M34.762,225.595c25.084,109.862,211.31,151.786,342.262,108.929   c129.701-42.448,212.358-186.755,180.357-288.095C543.096,1.19,460.075-8.983,449.372,67.834
 c-15.801,113.4,167.532,164.904,318.724,34.547"/>

  <!-- white path that covers the first one -->
  <path fill="none" 
   stroke="white" stroke-width="12" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="25,25" class="path" stroke-linecap="round"
 d="M34.762,225.595c25.084,109.862,211.31,151.786,342.262,108.929 c129.701-42.448,212.358-186.755,180.357-288.095C543.096,1.19,460.075-8.983,449.372,67.834 c-15.801,113.4,167.532,164.904,318.724,34.547"/>
</svg>
  
  
<svg  id="test" width="800px" height="369.643px" viewBox="0 0 800 369.643" enable-background="new 0 0 800 369.643">
 </svg>
```

Comment: What happens when the background is not a solid color? say, gradient?

Comment: Instead of covering your line with another one. Use a `<mask>` instead and animate the line in that.